# Django not found in my ubuntu system

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm trying to deploy django project on Ubuntu 14.04, but I’ve got  `import error: No module named ‘Django’` but actually the module exist. I reinstalled it many times but anyway the same problem occurs.

There is wsgy.py file

```
#wsgi.py
import os
import time
import traceback
import signal
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

# Calculate the path based on the location of the WSGI script.
apache_configuration= os.path.dirname(__file__)
project = os.path.dirname(apache_configuration)
workspace = os.path.dirname(project)
sys.path.append(workspace)
sys.path.append(project)


# Add the path to 3rd party django application and to django itself.
sys.path.append('/var/www/s052d78fe.fastvps-server.com/public_html/myv/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'msite.apache.override'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And  sys. path

```
'', '/var/www/s052d78fe.fastvps-server.com/public_html/myv/lib/python3.4', 
'/var/www/s052d78fe.fastvps-server.com/public_html/myv/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/var/www/s052d78fe.fastvps-server.com/public_html/myv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
'/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/var/www/s052d78fe.fastvps-server.com/public_html/myv/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

Thanks.

Comment: are you using the right virtualenv?

Comment: i hope yes, but i do not deled old virtualenv